# SetInexactRepeating Alarm not working

Tags: android

I want to fire an alarm in a particular day of the week. For example, every Monday at 4:30 pm.

The following code is what I have written for doing that, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void setAlarm(int day,int hour,int minit) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minit );
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Long alarmTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,
                                     24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 *7 , pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: Please explain completely and precisely what "it's not working" means. Bear in mind that `setInexactRepeating()` is inexact, and so the event can occur at any point within the week. Also note that your `Calendar` may be in the past, and you are not correctly handling that case. And, you can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if your alarm is scheduled.

Comment: hlw sir !
after turning on the alarm i changed the date and time of the emulator but the alarm is not working

Comment: i have given interval parameter 7 days is it ok ?